# How to Post a Radiobutton in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, radio-button, postback

I am trying to Post the value from a radio button with the below code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RdButton", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <input type="radio" id="HomeShow" name="HomeShow" value="AssemblyDrawings" checked/> Assembly Drawings
    <input type="radio" id="HomeShow" name="HomeShow" value="RelatedLiterature"/> Related Literature
    <input type="radio" id="HomeShow" name="HomeShow" value="StockParts"> List of stock parts
    </span>
}
```

With a basic Post form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RdButton(string HomeShow = "")     
{
    string rdValue = HomeShow;
    return View(rdValue);
}
```

How would I reference the value in the html? Thanks in advance

Edit:
Changed Form to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RdButton", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Show, "Assembly")   
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Show, "Literature")
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Show, "Parts")
   </span>
}
// would this work???
string rdobtn = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["RdButton"]);
if (rdobtn == "")
     {
        @Html.Partial("_gotopage"); 
     }
```

Comment: you need to add a submit button inside your form

Comment: Can I submit the form when the radiobutton is changed?

Comment: Sure, but you'll need javascript to submit it automatically, if thats what you're looking for. try searching for "submit form with javascript"

Comment: To reference the value from the radiobutton, would it be:
    
 `string rdobtn = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["RdButton"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post the form when radio button changes, you need some javascript code. Here is how to do it using jQuery:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

That piece of code will submit the form where the radio button resides.

If I were you I would create a model and pass that model to my view and create the radio buttons for it. Like this:

```
public class HomeShowModel 
{
    public string SelectedHomeShow { get; set; }
    // Other properties you may need
}
```

Then in your view you can use html helpers to create the radio button group for you:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.SelectedHomeShow ,"AssemblyDrawings")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedHomeShow , "RelatedLiterature")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedHomeShow , "StockParts")
```

The the controller will receive the value which was selected.

> // would this work???
>
> string rdobtn = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["RdButton"]);

Use the model to do that like this:

```
if (Model.SelectedHomeShow == "StockParts") { // code... }
```

But remember to pass the model to your view and make sure the `SelectedHomeShow` property is set. A better approach would be to make it so it reads like a business rule and therefore in your model, you can have another property for that specific rule:

```
public class HomeShowModel 
{
    public string SelectedHomeShow { get; set; }
    // Other properties you may need

    // Name this property something meaningful
    public bool NeedsPartial 
    { 
        return this.SelectedHomeShow == "StockParts";
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I test the value of the radiobutton in my html?

Comment: What do you mean test the value in my html?

Comment: `if (Model.SelectedHomeShow== "Assembly") {do stuff}`